# Start dynamic (Fragment)Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I think the question says it all: I want to create a new FragmentActivit in my code and start it. I think about something like this:

```
FragmentActivity fa = new FragmentActivity();              
fa.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, myFragment).commit();

// start fa
```

But how can I bring a new dynamic (Fragment)Activity to the front?

Comment: Pragnani is correct. What I would add is that FragmentActivity is a support class designed so you can use fragments in older versions of Android that do not natively support Fragment. It is used identically to Activity. It just adds methods to talk to Fragments that the older version of Activity lacked. So moving from FragmentActivity to FragmentActivity uses intents (just like activity). You use getSupportFramentManager() to start working with fragments living in the current FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Android create object for your Activity through life cycle methods. if you create object like this

```
FragmentActivity fa = new FragmentActivity();
```

life cycle methods won't execute and your activity is just like a normal class of no use.

use intent to go to the next Activity.

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, FragmentActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

if you just want to replace your fragment , you get your Activity of the fragment using `getActivity()` method.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, myFragment).commit();
```

try this